# Find, how the predictions occured?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I built a scikit SGD classifier. The X value is set of keywords and Y is a category.

Ex:

```
X - Y
Lunch - eat
dinner - eat
drink - eat
leave - event
plan - event
lunch plan - event
event - event
```

There are overlapping in the categories at "lunch and lunch event" keywords. These are example. But when overlapping its giving me wrong predict. I have used count vectorizer & tfidf transformer and send it to prediciton. But its giving wrong category.
**Any way to know which keyword it selected to predict the category?**
Ex: "The lunch is set" - Eat

```
X= "The birthday event is coming" - Event
//Fit transform done
predict = model.pred(X)    
print(predict) //Event
```

How to get the keywords, its used to predict this "Event" category?

Comment: You can use the `coef_` associated with each feature to get the importance of each feature (vocabulary words in Tfidf). For making it more simple you can use the [eli5 library](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/sklearn-text.html)

Comment: I have a saved model and feature file in pkl format. How do I use this at prediction? 
eli5.show_prediction(model, tfidf)
Got ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: See the tutorial I linked and follow that. If any error, post the complete code and the full error here.

Comment: ok. will check.

Comment: Its perfectly working in the notebook. Don;t know the way of console. to work out in real time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the weights assigend to the features with the coef_ attribute.

You can check the docs here:

> http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html

One possible solution for your problem is using 2 n grams, so you can have as features:

- lunch
- event
- lunch event

You can set it up in the ngram_range parameter in your count_vectorizer:

> http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html

Comment: How do I use the coef_ with predicted value? Any example?